# Can URLs be re-used for Event structured data?

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

My question is about using the event structured data for search engine rich results. I understand that the structured data Event schema requires separate leaf pages for each event if advertising multiple events. My question is, if I am only ever advertising one event at a time, is it acceptable to have a single URL but update the structured data for whatever the current event is? So there would only ever be one event advertised at a time at that URL. Or will this confuse search engines as they've previously associated a different event with that URL?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.